# Why can't I install fonts system-wide?

Tags: installation, fonts

I am having trouble installing some .ttfs that I earlier added to a Win7 system and now am trying to add to a 64-bit 12.04 LTS system.  I initially installed the fonts to my /home/.fonts folder and all worked well (after `sudo fc-cache -f -v` the fonts were available in LibreOffice).

Later decided to remove them from /home/.fonts and install in /usr/share/fonts/truetype so the fonts can be used globally.  First deleted from /home/.fonts folder and rebuilt cache.  Check LibreOffice and they were removed successfully.  Then copied in pasted into new folder /usr/share/fonts/truetype/myfonts and rebuilt cache.  There was an "invalid cache" warning, so rebuilt cache again.  No error this time.  Rebooted, but fonts not available in LibreOffice.  Went to tweaks/fonts section of Ubuntu Tweak, and the names of the installed fonts appear but the example characters below the names are black-bordered white rectangles (NOT "The quick brown..." in the selected font).

Uninstalled from /usr/share/fonts, reinstalled in /home/.fonts, and the fonts worked again in LibreOffice.  Uninstalled from /home/.fonts, installed in /usr/share/fonts, not working again (this time used `sudo fc-cache -rv`).

Additionally, I downloaded a new font from the web and placed file in /usr/share/fonts.  After `sudo fc-cache -f -v` this new font shows up working normally in LibreOffice.  None of the others work, however, unless in /home/.fonts.

Last try (as per WebbyIT)- tried `sudo mv ~/.fonts/name.font /usr/share/fonts/` for all of the fonts.  They are now located in /usr/share/fonts and working on my administrator account.  However, they still don't work for any other accounts (standard or guest).

Any ideas what the heck is going on???  I would still like to use these fonts globally.

Comment: Read permissions?

Comment: LOL... how you can't access **/usr/share/foo-moo-boo**? :D Guests can read that, how you can't? :D Give output of `cd /usr/share/fonts && ls -l`

Comment: total 15956
-rw-------  1 matty matty  95820 Jan  3 22:43 Optima-BoldItalic.ttf
-rw-------  1 matty matty 101984 Jan  3 22:43 Optima-Bold.ttf
-rw-------  1 matty matty  85824 Jan  3 22:43 Optima-ExtraBlack.ttf
-rw-------  1 matty matty 112384 Jan  3 22:43 Optima-Italic.ttf
-rw-------  1 matty matty 122744 Jan  3 22:43 Optima-Regular.ttf
drwxr-xr-x 22 root  root    4096 Jan 14 11:19 truetype
drwxr-xr-x  4 root  root    4096 Aug 23 11:56 type1
drwxr-xr-x  6 root  root    4096 Aug 23 11:56 X11                Truncated for space, but all fonts list the same as optima

Comment: @DoughnutJimmy comments like this should be added to the question via an edit operation.

Comment: I have the exact same problem though my font permission are OK! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a permissions issue.  When following Emre & ZDroid's suggestions, found the permissions were at level 600 (-rw-------).  For all fonts, I used:

> chmod 644 fontname.ttf

and now all users can use fonts.

What probably happened is since I initially installed in /home/.fonts the permissions were set for admin-only usage, and even though I deleted them and reinstalled in /usr/share/fonts those permission levels were carried over.

Answer (score 4):

Use move in terminal to move your fonts:

```
sudo mv ~/.fonts/name.font /usr/share/fonts/
```

After, rebuild your cache:

```
sudo fc-cache -f -v
```

Comment: Tried WebbyIT's answer.  Fonts are now in the /usr/share/fonts folder instead of /home/.fonts, and they work in my administrator account.  However, in my guest and standard accounts I still get the black-bordered white rectangle thing.